# Como puedo lograr que mi popup de JavaScript persista si se vuelve atrás

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente "problema" entre muchas comillas, y es que tengo un popup configurado apenas se ingresa a la pantalla de mi sitio y al recargar la página funciona pero si se es redireccionado a google y luego se vuelve atrás desde el navegador no se actualiza el popup, la idea es que al tocar que no en el popup siempre que se vuelva a la página aparezca el cartel de nuevo y solo sucede como mencione cuando se recarga la página o se va a otra y se pega en el url y se carga de nuevo, pero al ir al poner que no y ser redireccionado a google y volver atras el popup no se aplica.

```
let popup = localStorage.getItem('popup')

if (popup === null){
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Eres mayor de 18 años?',
        icon: 'warning',
        width: "50em",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Si',
        cancelButtonText: "No"
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
          Swal.fire(
            'Perfecto!',
            '',
            'success'
          )
          localStorage.setItem('popup', "false")
        } else{
            window.location.href="https://www.google.com.ar/?hl=es";
            localStorage.removeItem('popup')
        }
      })
  });
}
```

Esto aparece apenas se ingresa a la página
[image]
Luego se carga google si ponemos que no, luego al tocar arriba para volver a la página anterior

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se carga la página sin el popup
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y si cambias el orden de estas dos lineas: `window.location.href="https://www.google.com.ar/?hl=es";
localStorage.removeItem('popup')` no te funciona bien?

Comment: con el localstorage

Comment: Ninguna de esas sugerencias me ha funcionado

Comment: Prueba agregando tu sweetalert a una función y luego la llamas con JQuery: `$(document).ready(function() { Modal(); });`

Answer (score 0):

por medio de JS intenta mandar a llamar tu modal sin necesidad de depender del localStorage

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Eres mayor de 18 años?',
        icon: 'warning',
        width: "50em",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Si',
        cancelButtonText: "No"
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
          Swal.fire(
            'Perfecto!',
            '',
            'success'
          )
          localStorage.setItem('popup', "false")
        } else{
            window.location.href="https://www.google.com.ar/?hl=es";
            localStorage.removeItem('popup')
        }
      })
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.4.29/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body><h3>Hola Mundo</h3></body>
</html>
```